# Add DI for SendGrid instead of new object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, sendgrid

I have Service, that using SendGrid to send emails

I was doing it like this

```
 public class EmailSenderService : IEmailSenderService
{
    private SendGridClient SendGridClient { get; set; }
    
    private static IAwsService _awsService;

    private readonly IEmailSenderSettings _emailSenderSettings;


    public EmailSenderService(IAwsService awsService, IEmailSenderSettings emailSenderSettings)
    {
        _awsService = awsService;
        _emailSenderSettings = emailSenderSettings;
        SendGridClient = new SendGridClient(_emailSenderSettings.SendGridApiKey);
    }
```

But I need to use DI for Sendgrid.

So I rewrite code like this

```
 public class EmailSenderService : IEmailSenderService
{
    //private SendGridClient SendGridClient { get; set; }

    private readonly ISendGridClient _sendGridClient;
    
    private static IAwsService _awsService;

    private readonly IEmailSenderSettings _emailSenderSettings;


    public EmailSenderService(IAwsService awsService, IEmailSenderSettings emailSenderSettings, ISendGridClient sendGridClient)
    {
        _awsService = awsService;
        _emailSenderSettings = emailSenderSettings;
        _sendGridClient = sendGridClient;
        //SendGridClient = new SendGridClient(_emailSenderSettings.SendGridApiKey);
    }
```

And this is how it looks like in RegisterServices

```
  public static void RegisterServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IEmailSenderService, EmailSenderService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IEmailSenderSettings, EmailSenderSettings>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAwsService, AwsService>();
        services.AddScoped<ISendGridClient, SendGridClient>();
    }
```

But how I can pass SengGridApiKey when I use DI?

Comment: Where is the key comming from?

Comment: it coming from env variables - `_emailSenderSettings.SendGridApiKey`

Comment: Pass in IConfiguration into constructor and read from there.  Also out of interest why is your sendgrid also having aws service injected. Some advice separate out sendgrid so it only does sendgrid stuff.

Comment: in which constructor and how read it? @AliK

Comment: [This article should help](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/01/01/accessing-configuration-settings.aspx)